# Spring WebFlux: how to display a message from custom exception class on a Web page in case this exception is thrown?

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, exception, spring-webflux

Here is the fragment of my model's class, `Student`:

```
@Table
public class Student {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    private Integer age;

    public Student(String name, String surname, Integer age) {

        validateInput(name, surname, age);

        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    private void validateInput(String name, String surname, Integer age) {

        if (name == null || name.isBlank()) throw new InvalidNewStudentNameException(name);

        if (surname == null || surname.isBlank()) throw new InvalidNewStudentSurnameException(surname);

        if (age == null || age < 16) throw new InvalidNewStudentAgeException(age);
    }
}
```

So, in case of an attempt to create an object with invalid data, corresponding custom exception is thrown, and the object is not created.

One such custom class, `InvalidNewStudentAgeException`, goes as follows:

```
public class InvalidNewStudentAgeException extends RuntimeException {

    public InvalidNewStudentAgeException(Integer age) {

        super("Could not create a student: student's age, " + age + ", should not be empty or less than 16.");
    }
}
```

My endpoint for adding new student in `StudentController`:

```
@GetMapping("/add")
@ResponseBody
public Mono<Long> add(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String surname, @RequestParam Integer age) {

    return studentService.add(name, surname, age).map(student -> student.getId());
}
```

And corresponding method in `StudentService`:

```
@Override
public Mono<Student> add(String name, String surname, Integer age) {

    return client.execute("INSERT INTO student (age, name, surname) VALUES(:age, :name, :surname)")
                 .bind("age", age)
                 .bind("name", name)
                 .bind("surname", surname)
                 .as(Student.class).fetch().one();
}
```

I run the app and try to add invalid student (the one with age less than 16) via:

http://localhost:8080/add/?name=SomeName&surname=SomeSurname&age=14

I do indeed get my custom exception thrown, however, the message is only visible within my IDE in stack trace, but not in browser. The app terminates, and if I then access http://localhost:8080/, I get either Whitelabel Error Page with *Internal Server Error (500)*, or just the error without the page if I add `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false` to my *application.properties*

I tried various ways to handle this exception so that I'll get my custom error message for the user (browser), but no success so far.

Please help me with a proper way to catch my custom exceptions in the controller and handle it in a way that it'll display a message about invalid data in client's browser.

Even the dirty and obviously WRONG workaround of disabling whitelabel pages and adding *error.html* file in `src\main\resources\templates` project directory doesn't work for some reason...

Here is one way I tried to do this. I changed my `StudentController`'s `add()` method like this:

```
@GetMapping("/add")
@ResponseBody
public Mono<Long> add(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String surname, @RequestParam Integer age) {
    try {
        return studentService.add(name, surname, age).map(student -> student.getId());
    }
    catch (InvalidNewStudentAgeException invNewStudAgeEx) {
        return Mono.error(invNewStudAgeEx);
    }
    catch (InvalidNewStudentNameException invNewStudNameEx) {
        return Mono.error(invNewStudNameEx);
    }
    catch (InvalidNewStudentSurnameException invNewStudSurnameEx) {
        return Mono.error(invNewStudSurnameEx);
    }
}
```

I've added handlers like this:

```
 @ResponseStatus(
      value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      reason = "Invalid student's age: age should not be empty or less than 16.")
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidNewStudentAgeException.class)
    public void invalidNewStudentAgeHandler() {

    }

    @ResponseStatus(
      value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      reason = "Invalid student's name: the name should not be empty.")
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidNewStudentNameException.class)
    public void invalidNewStudentNameHandler() {

    }

    @ResponseStatus(
      value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      reason = "Invalid student's surname: the surname should not be empty.")
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidNewStudentSurnameException.class)
    public void invalidNewStudentSurnameHandler() {

    }
```

I figured out that if I change `HttpStatus`'s ENUM for invalid age handler and then try to add under-aged student, it does return different response code depending on the ENUM. So it does catch the exception in the handler, but how can I obtain MORE than just a number like 500 or 404? Can I somehow make the browser to display **"Invadin student's age..."** instead of just `HTTP ERROR 509`???

Comment: `client.execute` feels like a blocking call. It should be returning a `Mono.error` and not throw an exception if something goes wrong. What database driver are you using.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Thank you very much for your feedback!!!

This code, although certainly not without design/implementation flaws, is acceptable and it works in browser. This is my test task. I am newbie in Spring, Web and WebFlux, doing everything with Google. Last thing that I need to do with this already working app is to display error message in browser. I would highly appreciate if you could help with ANY POSSIBLE way to do this.

I edited my question. I use `Mono.error` there. I use r2dbc and in-memory H2 database: `spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:h2:mem:///studentlist;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`

Comment: @ThomasAndolf It seems that I've found a solution! Now I'm doing final refactoring and will then answer my own question with the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution thanks to this question:

[How can I add custom message after HTTP status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762481/how-can-i-add-custom-message-after-http-status-code)

My endpoint's final `add()` method from `StudentController` looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/add")
@ResponseBody
public Mono<Long> add(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String surname, @RequestParam Integer age) {
    try {
        return studentService.add(name, surname, age).map(student -> student.getId());
    }
    catch (InvalidInputException invalidInputException) {
        return Mono.error(invalidInputException);
    }
}
```

Now I have only one handler method in `StudentController`:

```
@ResponseStatus(
  value = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
  reason = "Invalid input data for new student.")
@ExceptionHandler(InvalidInputException.class)
public ResponseEntity invalidInputHandler(InvalidInputException e) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(e.getHttpStatus()).body(e.getMessage());
}
```

I've added a new class for generic `InvalidInputException` like this:

```
public class InvalidInputException extends RuntimeException {

    protected HttpStatus httpStatus;

    public InvalidInputException(HttpStatus httpStatus, String message) {

        super(message);

        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
    }

    public HttpStatus getHttpStatus() {
        return httpStatus;
    }
}
```

And one specific class for each invalid input. Here is an example of one such class, `InvalidNewStudentAgeException`:

```
public class InvalidNewStudentAgeException extends InvalidInputException {

    public InvalidNewStudentAgeException(HttpStatus httpStatus, Integer age) {
        super(httpStatus, "Could not create a student: student's age, " + age + ", should not be empty or less than 16.");
    }
}
```

Everything else is left unchanged, apart from specific exception constructors' signature. Exceptions are still being thrown as they were earlier, in the constructor of `Student` class through private method called there:

```
public Student(String name, String surname, Integer age) {

    validateInput(name, surname, age);

    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
}

private void validateInput(String name, String surname, Integer age) {

    if (name == null || name.isBlank()) throw new InvalidNewStudentNameException(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, name);

    if (surname == null || surname.isBlank()) throw new InvalidNewStudentSurnameException(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, surname);

    if (age == null || age < 16) throw new InvalidNewStudentAgeException(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, age);
}
```

Now everything works as expected. The flow is as follows:

1. Run the app;
2. Add "invalid" student via the link: http://localhost:8080/add/?name=TestName&surname=TestSurname&age=14
3. After that, go to localhost:8080 and see plain text message from my custom exception's constructor!

Comment: in webflux we commonly dont use `try/catch`. Because when an exception is thrown we automatically break the reactive chain, and this could give bad performance. Instead, we return `Mono.error`. `return studentService.add( ... )` should not be throwing an exception, it should instead during an error, return a `Mono.error` when something goes wrong.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Thank you for your feedback! On a positive side, this test task code for Java intern position has been considered acceptable. This test task is the first time I face reactive programming. :) So obviously I'm noob and my solution is bad, no surprise. 

If you could elaborate on your comment and post an answer where you show how I could have got same error message in browser without throwing exception in `add()` and using `try/catch`, I'll accept your answer instead of my own and you'll get points. :) I just can't accept a comment as an answer. :)